Read-only in ntfs partition
I use Kubuntu system with several SSD-devices. Most of them use NTFS because I have to use Windows as well.
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           3.2G  3.0M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/sdc2        55G   45G  7.6G  86% /
tmpfs            16G  235M   16G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
efivarfs        128K   48K   76K  39% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/sdc4       164G  105G   51G  68% /home
/dev/sdc3        94M  9.9M   84M  11% /boot/efi
tmpfs           3.2G  7.8M  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda3       107G   63G   44G  60% /media/username/projects
/dev/sde4       117G  3.9G  114G   4% /media/username/Kubuntu 24.
/dev/sda2       116G   63G   54G  54% /media/username/windows
/dev/sdb2       932G  761G  171G  82% /media/username/games
/dev/nvme0n1p1  1.9T  1.6T  281G  86% /media/username/storage
/dev/sdd1       466G  440G   26G  95% /media/username/hdd

Now one of mounted disk is read only and I don't understand why and how to fix it.
I'm talking about /dev/sda3
I checked it on Windows side and it works correctly there. I executed "chkdsk​" in Windows and it returns no errors.
But when I try to update any files and create one more on Kubuntu side I faced with error:
$ touch test
touch: cannot touch 'test': Read-only file system

When I try to use ntfsfix command:
$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda3
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking file system overflow... FAILED
Error: Failed to fix the alternate boot sector

Why? Could someone give some an advice? Rebooting the system doesn't help.

Try: sudo ntfsfix -bd /dev/sda3

While ntfsfix may help, you generally have to run repairs from Windows. If chkdsk needed. Or you may have Windows fast startup on, which sets hibernation flag making NTFS read only. Windows may turn fast startup back on with updates. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Does this answer your question? Why does my NTFS partition mount as read only?
